# PF SetPropertyActionListener breaks after first time

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, actionlistener

i've a problem that's driving me crazy! I have a component which renders a panel that have links on a footer. This links have, among other things, a title and HTML content I want to show. The idea is basically that when a link is clicked, the content of the page is changed via ajax and the html content of the link is shown (The footer remains on the page). Debbuging I've noticed that the first time a link is clicked the content does change, but then it doesn't. The setPropertyActionListener of the p.commandlinks in my composite component aren't executed any more after first time. I'have debbuged the project and this seems to be the problem, but I can't figure out why

Part of my composite component. Tryed setting an onstart and oncomplete js functions on the command link, and both are executed but the actionListeners aren't.

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="compId"/>
    <cc:attribute name="title"/>
    <cc:attribute name="bean"/>
    ...
</cc:interface>
<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>
    <p:panel id="#{cc.attrs.compId}" header="#{cc.attrs.title}" 
             widgetVar="#{cc.attrs.compId}"
             styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}">  
        <h:form>
            <p:dataList id="datalist-#{cc.attrs.compId}" value="#{cc.attrs.bean.currentList}"
                        type="definition" widgetVar="datalist-#{cc.attrs.compId}"
                        var="items" >

                <p:commandLink action="#{navBean.active}" update="@([id$=content])" styleClass="link"
                               value="#{items.descrInLang}" rendered="#{items.typeUrl eq 0}">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="infoPage" target="#{navBean.selection}"/>
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{items.descrInLang}" target="#{infoPage.title}" /> 
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{items.HTMLContent}" target="#{infoPage.HTMLContent}"/> 
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:dataList>
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
</cc:implementation>
```

Part of my Navigation Bean

```
public void active() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        setAlbums(selection.equals("albums"));
        setBand(selection.equals("band"));
        setConcerts(selection.equals("concerts"));
        setContacts(selection.equals("contacts"));
        setHome(selection.equals("home"));
        setSiteMap(selection.equals("siteMap"));
        setInfoPage(selection.equals("infoPage"));
    }

public void setSelection(String selection) {
        this.selection = selection;
    }

public boolean isInfoPage() {
        return infoPage;
    }

    public void setInfoPage(boolean infoPage) {
        this.infoPage = infoPage;
    }
```

The bean which stores the title & HTML Content to show. After the first click on the link, the getters of Title & HTML content are executed, but the setters aren't (as declared in the setPropertyActionListeners)

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class InfoPage implements Serializable {

    private String title;
    private String HTMLContent;

    public InfoPage() {
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getHTMLContent() {
        return HTMLContent;
    }
    public void setHTMLContent(String HTMLContent) {
        this.HTMLContent = HTMLContent;
    }   
    }
```

The content part of the template which indicates what content should be shown according to the selected page on the NavBean. I pass the HTML content and the title of the infoPage as a parameter

```
<h:head> 
    </h:head>    
    <h:body>
        <!-- the all containing file -->
        <ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="content">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{navBean.home}">
                        <ui:include src="homecontent.xhtml"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>   
                     ....
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{navBean.infoPage}">
                        <ui:include src="infoPage.xhtml">
                            <ui:param name="title" value="#{infoPage.title}"/>
                            <ui:param name="infoContent" value="#{infoPage.HTMLContent}"/>
                        </ui:include>
                    </h:panelGroup> 
                </h:panelGroup>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
```

The info Page.

```
<h:form id="infoPageForm">
    <p:panel id="infoPagePanel" header="#{title}">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="10">
            <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{infoContent}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: can you try by updating specifically the components you need, thus not using `update="@all"`? the point is avoiding the update of `h:form`. doing that might mess with ajax requests.

Comment: actually the orginal code is update="@([id$=content])", since we are working with templates - The only thing that is updated is the center content of the page, where the info of the link should be shown.